# UIButton not appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm a python/java programmer trying to learn iOS dev. I'm working within an open source game (for learning purposes – code can be found here: https://github.com/nathanborror/FlapFlap). I'm trying to programmatically add a button on the restart page where the user lands if he has lost the game. Here's my code which isn't giving me any errors but **the button is just not appearing**. Note that I've commented out code that was provided in the open source.

```
#import "NewGameScene.h"
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation NewGameScene {
  SKSpriteNode *_button;
    UIButton *myButton;
}

- (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
  if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    [self setBackgroundColor:[SKColor colorWithRed:.61 green:.74 blue:.86 alpha:1]];


      myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
      [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
      [myButton setTitle:@"Start!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      myButton.frame = CGRectMake(128, 32, self.size.width/2, self.size.height/10);
      [self.view addSubview:myButton];

      /*
    _button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1] size:CGSizeMake(128, 32)];
    [_button setPosition:CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/10)];
    [self addChild:_button];
       */
  }
  return self;
}

-(void) myMethod{
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:.4];
    GameScene *game = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
}

/*
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition doorsCloseHorizontalWithDuration:.4];
  GameScene *game = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
  [self.scene.view presentScene:game transition:transition];
}
 */

@end
```

Comment: try to log self.size to see whether it really has a value. `NSLog("%d",self.size);`

Comment: Reasons something wouldn't appear: 1) it has zero size 2) Its co-ordinates are such that it appears outside of the visible area of its parent view 3) its color is clear color 4) it has a color but its alpha is set to 0   5) it is hidden   6) another view gets added on top of it 7) your self.view is somehow nil so addSubview does nothing. In your case check 1) and 2) as the most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
myButton = [UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(128, 32, 100, 100);
      [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
      [myButton setTitle:@"Start!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

See if it appears on your view.